# Rust macro to format variable number of arguments

Tags: rust, macros

In writing Rust code, I frequently want to create my error type in an error block:

```
match something() {
  Ok(x) => {...},
  Err(e) => Err(MyError::new(format!("Something failed: {}", e)))
}
```

There is a lot of repeated code in the `Err` creation that I would like to extract to a function/macro.  Part of it is easy:

```
fn err(msg: String) -> Result<_, MyError> {
  Err(MyError::new(msg))
}
```

However, there is still boilerplate in the error block:

```
Err(e) => err(format!("Something failed: {}", e))
```

Since I also want to be able to do things like

```
Err(e) => err(format!("Unable to convert {}: {}", input, e)
```

I can't write a single function to get rid of the `format!`.  So clearly I need a macro.  I currently have

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! foo {
    ($base: expr, $(arg:expr),*) => {{
        Err(MyError::new(format!(base, arg)))
    }};
}
```

I don't get errors with the macro definition, but trying to use it gives me compilation errors:

```
    |
231 | macro_rules! foo {
    | ---------------- when calling this macro
...
245 |         let xxx = foo!("a", "b");
    |                             ^^^ no rules expected this token in macro call
```

The examples that I find online deal with processing the arguments one at a time, such as `bar![1,2,3]` to push each value onto a vector.  I can't figure out what I need to do to get the macro to match and then pass all the arguments to another macro.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in the `anyhow` crate which contains an `anyhow!` macro doing something similar.

Your macro is almost good, you're just missing an extra `$` in the declaration, and $ prefixes at the usage site.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! foo {
    ($base: expr, $($args:tt),*) => {{
        Err(MyError::new(format!($base, $($args),*)))
    }};
}
```

Note that you can also pass the whole thing to `format!` without having a separate `base` parameter.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! foo {
    ($($args:tt),*) => {{
        Err(MyError::new(format!($($args),*)))
    }};
}
```

If you wanted to prefix the error message with another string, `format_args!` can be used instead of `format!` to save a memory allocation.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! foo {
    ($($args:tt),*) => {{
        Err(MyError::new(format!("Something failed: {}", format_args!($($args),*))))
    }};
}
```

Comment: If `MyError` is defined in lib.rs, then using `$crate::MyError` means if you use the macro in another file, you don't need to import `MyError`

Comment: I suggest `($($arg:tt)*) => {{ ... format_args!($($arg)*) ... }}` -- without the comma and singular (this is how `format!` itself is declared

Comment: Also, you don't need `#[macro_export]` most of the time